# Forbidding Apostrophe while typing in HTML textBox

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a simple maybe JS to forbid apostrophe onKeyUp or OnKeyPress kind of thing. For ex, every time user presses a key if it was apostrophe (Jame's Pizza) replace it with space. I don't want to process it in PHP
I found a code but it ties the JS to the textfield Name which I don't want. I need something global,

Comment: Show us the code you found, we can help you to adapt it. What do you mean by "something global"?

Comment: "I don't want to process it in PHP."  You're going to need to process it in PHP as well since you can't trust user input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always better to prevent the keystroke than to retroactively delete it. To accomplish this, you need to intercept the `keypress` event (`keyup` is too late):

```
document.getElementById('yourTextBoxID').onkeypress = function () {
    if (event.keyCode === 39) { // apostrophe
        // prevent the keypress
        return false;
    }
};​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TSB9r/

If you only want to stop the `'` from appearing in the box but would like the keypress event to propagate to parent elements, replace the `return false;` with `event.preventDefault();`. (suggested by Eivind Eidheim Elseth in the comments)

Comment: It might be more idiomatic to use `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`

Comment: @EivindEidheimElseth they perform different things - `return false` is equivalent to calls to both `preventDefault` **AND** `stopPropagation`.

Comment: @NickBeranek key codes change depending on whether you are in keyup/down or keypress, see http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html (wicked annoying, i know). essentially, `keypress`'s keycode takes modifiers into account (in this case, the shift key) where keyup/down do not.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below functions. It grabs all of the `input` elements on the page and assigns `keydown` and `keyup` event handlers to each of them. If they detect an apostrophe, it will call the `preventDefault()` method..

```
function listen(event, elem, func) {
  if (elem.addEventListener) return elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);
  else elem.attachEvent('on' + event, func);
}

listen('load', window, function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
    keyHandler(i);
  }
  function keyHandler(i) {
    listen('keydown', inputs[i], function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 222) { // 222 is the keyCode for apostrophe
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
    listen('keyup', inputs[i], function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 222) { // 222 is the keyCode for apostrophe
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  }
});
```