# Javascript keycode clash: "right arrow" and "single quote"

Tags: javascript, keycode

The following script does what it should, that is, it reacts on the keys "arrow left" and "arrow right". However, due to a keycode clash, it reacts on a single quote as well. It makes it impossible to enter that character into an input field. Can anything be done about that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  onload = function(){
    document.onkeypress=function(e){
      if(window.event) e=window.event;
      var keycode=(e.keyCode)?e.keyCode:e.which;

      switch(keycode){
        case 37: window.location.href='set.jsp?index=5';
          break;
        case 39: window.location.href='set.jsp?index=7';
          break;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: For me `'` is 222. I tested here: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Try keydown instead perhaps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121252/how-to-get-right-left-up-and-bottom-arrow-key-value-in-jquery

Comment: @Halcyon For me, the test shows 222 as well. Still, this script reacts when a single quote is pressed, and an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008215/forbidding-apostrophe-while-typing-in-html-textbox also uses the keycode 39 for a single quote.

Comment: *keyCode* and *which* are deprecated, you should use *key*. As others have said, the *keypress* event doesn't provide a key/keyCode/which value for keys that don't represent printable characters in all browsers, so use *keypress* or *keyup* and something like: `var keycode = e.key || e.keyCode || e.which`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user presses the single quote key, the `e.keyCode` property is zero, and the `e.which` property is 39. Executing `String.fromCharCode(39)` returns a single quote.

You want the `keyCode` if that property is in the event object:

```
var keycode = "keyCode" in e ? e.keyCode : e.which;
```

That way you get zero for the keyCode when that property exists in the event object, and when the `which` property also exists.

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;

    var keyCode = "keyCode" in event ? event.keyCode : event.which;

    switch (keyCode) {
        case 37: console.log("37 was pressed", event); break;
        case 39: console.log("39 was pressed", event); break;
    }
};
```

Edit #1: Other commenters and answers are correct. I forgot you shouldn't be detecting control keys with `keypress` events. Changed to `onkeydown`.

Full HTML example that works cross browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Key Codes Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onkeydown = function(event) {
            event = event || window.event;

            var keyCode = "keyCode" in event ? event.keyCode : event.which;

            switch (keyCode) {
                case 37: console.log("37 was pressed", event); break;
                case 39: console.log("39 was pressed", event); break;
            }
        };
    </script>
    <input type="text" size="30">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that [*keyCode* is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.keyCode), as is [*which*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.which), [*key*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#relationship-between-key-code) should be used where available. Also see [*Legacy keyboard events*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#KeyboardEvent-supplemental-interface).

Answer (score 1):

As it is a text input, it seems you'd also have a problem when someone is trying to use the arrow keys to move the cursor within the input. Thus, stopping event propagation/bubbling should be used, and can solve the main issue you're asking about.

```
// assuming you've grabbed an input in var input_ele
input_ele.onkeypress = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
};
```

Using this will stop the `keypress` event from leaving the input element, thereby never reaching the document element to trigger the unwanted behavior. In other words, you don't break the expected behavior of a very standard control element.

Comment: While it does not solve the main issue, it for sure has helped me to fix another problem in the app.

Answer (score 1):

`keypress` should not capture control keys like left/right arrow. if you use `keydown` event, single quote keycode is 222 definitely no conflict

Answer (score 0):

Use `keydown` instread of `keypress`

jS:

```
document.onkeydown=function(event){
  if(window.event) event=window.event;
  var keycode=(event.keyCode)?event.keyCode:event.which;
  switch(keycode){
    case 37: alert("an arrow");
      break;
    case 39: alert("another arrow");
      break;
  }
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/p9x1Lj4u/2/