# jquery clash: “right arrow” and “single quote” getting same keycode in keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

Similar to this question but a bit different
[Javascript keycode clash: "right arrow" and "single quote"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861696/javascript-keycode-clash-right-arrow-and-single-quote)

He is using javascript while I am using jquery. 
I cannot use keydown event. I want to manage  it in keypress event only.

I want to allow Right arrow(& other navigation keys) but disallow entering single quote. both are getting keycode 39.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".InjectionSafe").keypress(InjectionSafe);
    });

    function InjectionSafe(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        console.log(charCode);
        if (charCode === 9 || charCode == 8 || charCode == 46 // TAB , backspace, delet, left arrow and right arrow
            || charCode == 37 ) { //was pressed
            return true;
        }
        //if (!(charCode != 222 && charCode != 188 && charCode != 190 && charCode!=39)) { // ' < >
        if (!(charCode != 60 && charCode != 62 && charCode != 39)) { // ' < >
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

updated fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/g2g0sbfo/
Type something & use navigation keys.

**Update:**  I can confirm that this issue is only in firefox(My version is 59.0.1). IE, chrome & opera work fine.

Comment: arrow keys are only triggered by `keydown` and `keyup`, not `keypress`

Comment: have you tried any solution from the link you provide? for example, change keypress to keydown ?

Comment: @scraaappy I want to manage it in key press only.See my code is different from the link

Comment: @Zenoo  as you said ,I expect that right arrow key should not trigger a keypress but it is in doing so in Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I toyed around with Firefox to see what's happening.

Here is what I got :

You can check `originalEvent.key` to see which key was actually pressed.

If you pressed `'`, `originalEvent.key = "'"`.

If you pressed the right arrow, `originalEvent.key = "ArrowRight"`.

```js
$(document).on('keypress', e => {
  var charCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;

  $('body').html(charCode);
  if (charCode == 39) {
    if (e.originalEvent.key == 'ArrowRight') { //Right arrow
      $('body').append('<p>Right arrow</p>');
    } else {
      //Single quote
      $('body').append('<p>Single quote</p>');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```